# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't build Play project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm seeing some strange behavior in IDEA v13 and v14EAP. I have a pretty big Play project. When I try to build it with Build->Make Project I see "All files are up to date" message

But when I actually launch it, I see compilation errors reported by Play framework. Is there any way to force IDEA to perform actual build and report errors?

Comment: I'm facing this problem on 14. I'm reverting to 13 for now.